# Register inherited QObject's meta object to QJSEngine

Tags: python, pyqt, qmetaobject, qjsengine, pyqt6

I would like to inherit the `QObject` class, and register the inherited class's meta object to a QJSEngine instance, so that I can call `let instance = new TrialObject();` in JavaScript. Here is my code:

```py
from PyQt6.QtQml import QJSEngine
from PyQt6.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QObject


JS = """
(function() {
    let a = new TrialObject();
    return a;
})();
"""


class AttributeHandler(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)


class Main:
    def __init__(self):

        self.jsHandler = QJSEngine()
        self.jsHandler.globalObject().setProperty("TrialObject", self.jsHandler.newQMetaObject(QObject.staticMetaObject))

        r = self.jsHandler.evaluate(JS)

        print(r.toString())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QCoreApplication([])
    main = Main()
    app.exec()
```

When (as above), I use `QObject.staticMetaObject` as the `TrialObject`, the JavaScript runs fine, and returns the `QObject` back to Python. Therefore `QObject` is invokable and working. But when I try replacing `QObject.staticMetaObject` with `AttributeHandler.staticMetaObject`, I get the error:

`TypeError: AttributeHandler has no invokable constructor`

... showing that AttributeHandler is not invokable. By "invokable" I mean that JavaScript can create a new instance of the class `TrialObject`, which I would like to be a class that has been created in Python, and inherits `QObject`.

How can I register an inherited `QObject`'s meta object to `QJSEngine` such that it is invokable IE a new instance can be instantiated in JavaScript?

(PyQt6, Python 3.9, Windows 10)

---

**EDIT 1**

Running `AttributeHandler.staticMetaObject.constructorCount()` returns `0`, where-as for a normal `QObject`, it returns `2`, so i think that the problem lies in the constructor actually being recognised by the meta object system. `Q_INVOKABLE` doesn't exist in `PyQt`, so I have tried decorating the `__init__` with `pyqtSlot()`, but this doesn't have the deired effect either.

Comment: What does *that it is invokable* mean? Could you provide a test where it is verified that *QObject.staticMetaObject* does not comply with what *that it is invokable* means

Comment: @eyllanesc, I've edited the question and discussed what I meant by "invokable"